# How to map the Instances with the user who created it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

This is what I am trying to do:

We have IAM in place and each user logs in to the AWS console with his/her respective email address and create the EC2 instance. I being the Administrator, when I login to AWS console, I see a whole bunch of Instance created and many of them are not even utilized. However, I am not able to figure who created those instances.

**Question:**
Is there a way to map EC2 Instances with the email address of the user who created it? I have thoroghly explored EC2 CLI but it was of no help. Is there a way to do this via SDK? OR did I overlook something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple without having to use an SDK outside of the CLI, you could create the tag "Owner" and have your users tag their instances they create with their name/email. You can then click on the "Show/Hide" button in the EC2 Management Console to add your tag to the other data that is shown in the console. It allows you to filter and sort instances by the value of the tag. This isn't a fail proof solution since it depends on your users to create the tags, but it is simple.

Comment: Thanks. Will explore it.